# Array value not working as intended

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, math

I'm making a fence using terrain representation where 1's are fences and 0's are empty spaces. Here is the code:

```
package assignment_2;

public class Fencing {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean b = true;
    int i;
    int j;
    int[] [] map = 
        {
                {0, 1, 1, 0},
                {1, 2, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 4},
                {1, 3, 0, 0}
        };
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (map[i][j] != 1 && map[i][j] != 0){
                b = false;

                if (b == false){
                    System.out.println("Map does not have the correct format");
                    while (i < 4 && j < 4){
                        System.out.println("--> A value of " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);
                        i++;
                        j++;

                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                System.out.println("The map is valid");
                return;

                }   
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Right now this code scrolls through the array values, and if there are values that are not 1's or 0's then it reports them back to the user. If there are errors it displays all incorrect numbers. The problem with it is that after it picks up the first error, it scrolls diagonally through the rest of the array and shows those values instead of showing the errors (The numbers that aren't 1's or 0's). I think it has something to do with this part of the code:

```
while (i < 4 && j < 4){
    System.out.println("--> A value of " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);
    i++;
    j++;
```

Does anyone know what to change about it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve as output ultimately?

Comment: Did you step through the code one line at a time in your debugger? It's doing exactly what you told it to do.  What are you expecting for output?

Comment: Do you want to collect all of the values for later use and display them all at once, or do you have to do the scan in-place?  (Visually it makes little difference; from a coding standpoint there's a substantial difference.)

Comment: I'm expecting it to display something like this for each of the errors: --> A value of 2 was found at 1,1. It is displaying something like that, but instead of actual errors it is going diagonally through the array and is displaying the (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) values when I want it to go from left to right and move downward.

Comment: The block you have identified is indeed your culprit. Why is it there at all? Get rid of the "while" loop and get rid of the incrementors inside it. Leave just the `println`.

Comment: in its current form, your program gets to `System.out.println("The map is valid");` the first time, exits, and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the program as :

```
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (map[i][j] != 1 && map[i][j] != 0){
               b = false; // greedy approach can break or return here as well
                        System.out.println("--> A value of " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);

                        }
                    }
               if (b == false){
                    System.out.println("Map does not have the correct format"); }
                else{
                System.out.println("The map is valid"); }
```

Comment: To make this answer better, you could explain why the original is not working (i++ AND j++ means that on each error (the first is at 2,2) we check the next index (2+1) and (2+1) or 3,3 in the case of that first match

Answer (score -1):

```
 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            //set b to true for each Map
            b = true;
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (map[i][j] != 1 && map[i][j] != 0) {
                        //found incorrect value, set b to false
                        b = false;
                        System.out.println("Map is Invalid :"+map[i][j]);
                    }  
                }
                //If b is true, then ONLY Map is VALID
                if(b) {
                    System.out.println("Map is VALID");
                }
            }
```